# Is it possible to transform a parsimonious XML to a full HTML table using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, qxmlquery

VERY IMPORTANT NOTE: I am using QtXmlPattern (a not fully implemented XSLT 2.0 processor with a few bugs in what's implemented...)

I have a well formed XML file with data defined in a four level array as in:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c day="20150221">
      <d>...</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150222">
      <d>...</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150223">
      <d>...</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c day="20150219">
      <d>...</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150221">
      <d>...</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150223">
      <d>...</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
  </b>
  ...
</a>
```

The result should include all the days, but as we can see each `<b>` list may have a different set of days. Yet the result needs to have all the days for all the `<b>` tags. If data is not available, the result remains empty or zero as might be.

I found a way to gather all the days in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="days" select="distinct-values(/a/b/c/@day)"/>
```

But I don't see how to generate the final results which would look something like this:

```
<table>
  <th>
    <td>20150219</td>
    <td>20150221</td>
    <td>20150222</td>
    <td>20150223</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>data from <d> tag on 20150219</td>
    <td>data from <d> tag on 20150221</td>
    <td>data from <d> tag on 20150222</td>
    <td>data from <d> tag on 20150223</td>
  </tr>
  ...[repeat for various data and calculation on the data]...
</table>
```

My problem is that the variable is not a list of nodes, just a list of strings and I'm not too sure how I can loop through a list of string.

Just in case, for those who do not know about the QXmlQuery parser, the `xsl:for-each-group` command does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can (with XSLT 2.0, not sure whether your chosen processor supports that then) simply do

```
<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/">
```

to store the main document node in a variable you will later on, then define a key

```
<xsl:key name="by-date" match="a/b/c/d" use="../@day"/>
```

and then references `d` items on a day with

```
<xsl:for-each select="$days">
  <xsl:variable name="d-on-day" select="key('by-date', ., $main-doc)"/>
```

That `key()` call with three argument is new in XSLT 2.0, if not supported then try

```
<xsl:for-each select="$days">
  <xsl:variable name="day" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$main-doc">
    <xsl:variable name="d-on-day" select="key('by-date', $day)"/>
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

If the `key` function is not available then you need to write the references as e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="d-elements" select="/a/b/c/d"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$days">
  <xsl:variable name="day" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$d-elements[../@day = $day]">...</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Ah! I see... I was getting this error `Error XPTY0004 in file:///home/alexis/tmp/a.xsl, at line 1, column 1: Required type is node(), but xs:untypedAtomic was found.` because attempting to access the XML data directly from within the `<xsl:for-each select="$days">` fails. Now I understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Arrrgh.... `key()` is not defined! It understands the `<xsl:hey ...>` but not the function.

Comment: @AlexisWilke That's a crappy XSLT processor if you forgive my French - `xsl:key` is pretty useless without `key()`...

Comment: Are you sure it fails on `key()` calls in general? Or only on the XSLT 2.0 call with three arguments? I will edit to show how to use the function with two arguments.

Comment: Yes. The processor tells me the function does not exist at all. `Error XPST0017 in file:///home/alexis/tmp/a.xsl, at line 1, column 39: No function with name fn:key is available.`

Comment: @AlexisWilke, I added a sample that does not make use of keys.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you need, but sometimes it is easier to comment on an attempted solution than trying to explain. You definitely have to use a *key* to find distinct attribute values.

Do not loop through a list of strings, but through a sequence of `c` elements that are unique with respect to the value of their `day` attribute (which, in the end, is the same). The technique I use below is described by Jeni Tennison [here](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) because it is commonly used for grouping problems.

**XML Input**

In my opinion, a sensible input includes actual values for `d` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c day="20150221">
      <d>data from day 20150221</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150222">
      <d>data from day 20150222</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150223">
      <d>data from day 20150223</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c day="20150219">
      <d>data from day 20150219</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150221">
      <d>data from day 20150221</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
    <c day="20150223">
      <d>data from day 20150223</d>
      <e>...</e>
    </c>
  </b>
  <!--...-->
</a>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="day-from-c" match="c" use="@day" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <table>

            <xsl:variable name="days" select="b/c[generate-id() =
        generate-id(key('day-from-c', @day)[1])]"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="$days">
                <xsl:sort select="@day"/>
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@day"/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$days">
                    <xsl:sort select="@day"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/a/b/c[@day = current()/@day]/d"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**HTML Output**

It is still not clear to me what should happen if there are multiple `d` elements on the same day.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<hmtl>
   <table>
      <th>20150219</th>
      <th>20150221</th>
      <th>20150222</th>
      <th>20150223</th>
      <tr>
         <td>data from day 20150219</td>
         <td>data from day 20150221 data from day 20150221</td>
         <td>data from day 20150222</td>
         <td>data from day 20150223 data from day 20150223</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</hmtl>
```

Try this solution [online on xsltransform](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMr).